# Add properties at runtime

Tags: c#, properties, runtime

I have a class which the programmer can use to dynamically add new properties. For that it implements the `ICustomTypeDescriptor` to be able to override `GetProperties()` method.

```
public class DynamicProperty
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Collection<Attribute> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class DynamicClass : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    // Collection to code add dynamic properties
    public KeyedCollection<string, DynamicProperty> Properties
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    // ICustomTypeDescriptor implementation
    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        // Properties founded within instance
        PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        // Fill property collection with founded properties
        PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection = 
            new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());

        // Fill property collection with dynamic properties (Properties)
        foreach (var prop in Properties)
        {
            // HOW TO?
        }

        return propsCollection;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to iterate over the Properties list to add each property to `PropertyDescriptorCollection`?

Basically I want the programmer to be able to add a `DynamicProperty` to a collection which will be handled by `GetProperties`. Something like:

```
new DynamicClass()
{
    Properties = {
        new DynamicProperty() {
            Name = "StringProp",
            Type = System.String,
            Value = "My string here"
        },

        new DynamicProperty() {
            Name = "IntProp",
            Type = System.Int32,
            Value = 10
        }
    }
}
```

Now those `Properties` would be setted to instance properties whenever `GetProperties`is called. Am I thinking this the right way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are already creating a collection like this:

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection = 
            new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
```

But the collection you are creating only has the existing properties, not your new properties.

You need to supply a single array concatenated from the existing properties and your new properties.

Something like this:

```
instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().Concat(customProperties).ToArray()
```

Next problem: you need `customProperties` which is a collection of `PropertyDescriptor`.  Unfortunately `PropertyDescriptor` is an abstract class so you don't have an easy way to create one.

We can fix this though, just define your own `CustomPropertyDescriptor` class by deriving from `PropertyDescriptor` and implementing all the abstract methods.

Something like this:

```
public class CustomPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    private Type propertyType;
    private Type componentType;

    public CustomPropertyDescriptor(string propertyName, Type propertyType, Type componentType)
        : base(propertyName, new Attribute[] { })
    {
        this.propertyType = propertyType;
        this.componentType = componentType;
    }

    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { return true; }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return componentType; } }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { return 0; /* your code here to get a value */; }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return propertyType; } }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { SetValue(component, null); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { /* your code here to set a value */; }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { return true; }
}
```

I haven't filled in the calls to get and set your properties; those calls depend on how you've implemented the dynamic properties under the hood.

Then you need to create an array of `CustomPropertyDescriptor` filled in with information appropriate to your dynamic properties, and concatenate it to the basic properties as I described initially.

The `PropertyDescriptor` not only **describes** your properties, it also enables client to actually get and set the values of those properties.  And that's the whole point, isn't it!

Comment: `propertyType` is the type of the property itself right? What about componentType? Is it the Type of the object where the property sits?

Comment: The `propertyType` is the type of the dynamic property.  If you have a dynamic integer property called `Count`, it would be `typeof(int)`.  The `componentType` is the type of the class that has the the dynamic properties, e.g. `typeof(MyDynamicPropertyClass)`.

Comment: Just one more question. This way if a property, previously added through `Properties` list, is dynamically accessed (using `var` for example) can I be sure that `GetProperties()` is used to access said property?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Implementing dynamic properties like this only works when the client (the entity actually looking up, reading and writing properties) supports the `TypeDescriptor` way of doing things.  This is sometimes called "the component model" and not all property consumers support it.  For example WPF **does** support it, for example for databinding.  Also, WinForms supports the component model for `PropertyGrid`.  But in other places property are just properties and the component model is not used.  The simplest thing is to see if it works for your application.