# .NET Reflection: Unable to retrieve Dynamic Properties

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

**I am adding dynamic property to a class with the help of Reflection. But unable to find new/dynamic Properties.**

**Process:** I have created a DynamicClass by implementing ICustomTypeDescriptor Interface and implements the function GetPropertiesI, I did my all manipulation here to get updated properties but it is not working..

My DynamicClass code is here:

```
public class DynamicClass : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    // Collection to code add dynamic properties
    /*
    KeyedCollection<string, DynamicProperty> _properties;
    public KeyedCollection<string, DynamicProperty> Properties
    {
        get;// { return _properties; }
        set;// { _properties = value; }
    }
    */
    public void AddProperty(DynamicProperty _property)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Fill property collection with founded properties
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection =
        new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());

    propsCollection.Add(new DynamicPropertyDescriptor(
        _property.ComponentType,
        _property.PropertyName,
        _property.PropertyType,
        _property.Component,
        _property.Value
    ));
}

public void AddProperties(KeyedCollection<string, DynamicProperty> _properties)
{
    PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Fill property collection with founded properties
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection =
        new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());

    foreach (var p in _properties)
    {
        propsCollection.Add(new DynamicPropertyDescriptor(
            p.ComponentType,
            p.PropertyName,
            p.PropertyType,
            p.Component,
            p.Value
            ));
    }
}

PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
{
    PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection =
        new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
    return propsCollection;
}

// ICustomTypeDescriptor implementation
PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
{
    // Properties founded within instance
    PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    // Fill property collection with founded properties
    PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection =
        new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
    //propsCollection.Cast.<CustomPropertyDescriptor>().Concat(Properties).ToArray();

    // Fill property collection with dynamic properties (Properties)

    //List<DynamicPropertyDescriptor> _dynamicPropertyDescriptors = new List<DynamicPropertyDescriptor>();

    //instanceProps.Cast<DynamicPropertyDescriptor>().Concat().ToArray();
    return propsCollection;
}

#region ICustomTypeDescriptor Members

public System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public string GetClassName()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public string GetComponentName()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public TypeConverter GetConverter()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
{
    PropertyInfo[] instanceProps = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    PropertyDescriptorCollection propsCollection =
        new PropertyDescriptorCollection(instanceProps.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>().ToArray());
    return propsCollection;

    /*
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection collection = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true);

        PropertyDescriptorCollection newList = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(new PropertyDescriptor[0]);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in collection)
        {
            Attribute a = prop.Attributes[typeof(CategoryAttribute)];

            if (a != null && ((CategoryAttribute)a).Category == "SixDisciplines")
                newList.Add(prop);
        }

        return newList;
    }
    else
        //The control must be passed to the method.
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, attributes, true);
     */
}

public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

#endregion
```

}

Comment: `GetProperties()` reflects over the compile-time `type`, not the instance.  That's why you're not seeing the new properties.

Comment: process not firing the function ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()...!!

Answer (score 4):

To retrieve runtime properties of an object, use the [`System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z8d1f70.aspx) method, instead of the [`Type.GetProperties()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332493%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method, which only retrieves compile-time properties of the `type`.

Comment: process not firing the function ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()...!!

Comment: What you want to do seems unnecessarily complicated.  Are you sure the C# `dynamic` keyword wouldn't suffice (what version of the framework are you using)?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166236/add-properties-at-runtime, and then have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/parthopdas/archive/2006/01/03/509103.aspx, near the bottom.