# Insert properties to class in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to insert properties dynamically to a class.
I need to load properties from database and show it in PropertyGrid, but I want to it to be build in run time, it means that I want to insert property definition to database and to load it to a class(My Class) in runtime.

e.g - if the data base contains row that define property (e.g Name of type string)
the class should something like this:

```
public MyClass
{
   public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

I also tried to do it using dynamic but it failed.
any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: i don't know if this will work with linq and anonymous objects?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166236/add-properties-at-runtime

Comment: Doing this is a *lot* of work, and usually not worth it. At the point that you're doing this, I would (very unusually for me) suggest: just use a `DataTable` for this part of the code - that already has a fully working "add columns(===properties) at runtime" implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Comment: Does ExpandoObject support the APIs required for PropertyGrid, though? It certainly doesn't seem to.

Comment: According to [this](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions/287866), it does only if you provide your own ICustomTypeDescriptor. Perhaps you could use a different sort of grid since it is Enumerable.

Comment: to be fair, you can also use `TypeConverter` (not just `ICustomTypeDescriptor`) - or you can use `TypeDescriptionProvider` - but in all of these cases you end up writing a ton of code for very little business benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Simple.Data`](http://blog.markrendle.net/2010/08/05/introducing-simple-data/) to do this. It fetches data from the database and constructs dynamic objects from the query :)

Comment: Neither of these will like you adding properties *at runtime*...?

Comment: well I see, but I need to generate it on the client side, I'm getting the properties from database fills dataObject with this properties(only definitions) and the class that should contain the properties is generated from the object, in the client side, withoud any access to DB.

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean... Who is fetching the data from the DB? Do you have a server which does it for you?